# Permanent solution for Long number is excel shown with plus

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

A csv file is created from a python code of mine, once I open the csv I see that the long numbers are displayed with  **+** in the middle.

```
Example
1.4554564548482346E+19
```

Looking for answers I found out that all I have to do it select the column, go to Format cells then go to Custom and then choose the option that says 0.

That solve the problem.
My question is if there is any approach to make this solution permanent.
So I don’t have to go through the same procedure every time I create a new csv file.

I don’t want to create any macros, I was hoping is there is a chance to change the settings of excel so it is custom.

Comment: it's not just the `+` in the middle. Did you notice the `E` before that? It's the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and Excel can also show that depending on the column width and the number format

Comment: @phuclv, I forgot to mention that in the question. i am just looking for a permanent solution regarding that

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to modify the python code so that it saves numbers in the right format (excel is *really* clunky for this kind of thing). Using the Numpy library, you can specify how you want to save a value - the code is: 
`np.format_float_positional(num, trim='-')`

Another option would be to save it in the csv as text (as far as python is concerned). You can simply save each value using `f'{a:.20f}'`. Python thinks this is a string, but excel will automatically convert it to a number when you import it.

A more complete description is available in a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106536/4741979)

***Another*** option would be to set it up so you don't actually open the csv file in excel, you just use the import from text function to set up a data link. This means that you can have a data-input sheet (with the link) and links to it from another sheet (that is correctly formatted). This would also allow you to keep the excel file open while running your python code without locking the csv file and getting a python un-writeable error...

***Another*** ***Another*** option
Depending on the the nature of `qu.text` (as described in comments) if it's a list or array you could nest `for` loops and have

```
 output = []
 for q in qu.text:
     output.append(f'{q:.20f}')
 row["selects" ]= output
```

It's not best practice and it really isn't pretty, but...

Comment: you have any idea on how to implement your code into this             ```for qu in sn.findall('.//Selects'):
                row['selects'] = qu.text```     . This is that part of the that parses the  numbers from Selects to a csv file

Comment: It looks like it's dropping a row in at a time. It all depends on the nature of `qu.text` is it a list or array or just a single number? It's not pretty but you could nest for loops and have `output = [] for q in qu.text: output.append(f'{q:.20f}') row["selects" ]= output` (with proper line breaks obvs)?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would add this to your answer.. It parses numbers from an xml file into the csv